# Counting the number of occurrences per year in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234], 'year':['2017', '2017', '2018', '2018', '2018'], 'count_to_today':[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]})
df
     id  year  count_to_today
0  1234  2017               1
1  1234  2017               2
2  1234  2018               3
3  1234  2018               3
4  1234  2018               4
```

And I need to count how many times `count_to_today` happens in each year per `id`. i.e. I have a running count since the beginning of time, and **I want to count the number of times it increments per year.**

```
           count_in_year
id   year               
1234 2017              2
     2018              2
```

I'm a bit confused about how to do this. I know I need to groupby `id` and `year` but I can't figure out how to get `.count()` or `.value_counts()` to give me the counts per year.

Comment: Guys, "I want to count the number of times it increments per year."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff` and `groupby`:

```
df.count_to_today.diff().ne(0).groupby([df.id, df.year]).sum()

id    year
1234  2017    2.0
      2018    2.0
Name: count_to_today, dtype: float64
```

---

```
(df.count_to_today.diff()
   .ne(0)
   .groupby([df.id, df.year])
   .sum()
   .astype(int)
   .reset_index())

     id  year  count_to_today
0  1234  2017               2
1  1234  2018               2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count ID per Year
try using -

```
df[['ID','Year']].groupby('Year').count()
```

or-

```
df[['ID','Year']].groupby('Year').agg('count')
```

Change variables as you want to get your result.

Comment: This does not address the part of the question that asks "I want to count the number of times it increments per year."...

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:

```
df[['ID','Year']].groupby('Year').count()
```

and

```
df[['ID','Year']].groupby('Year').agg('count')
```

I hope this will work fine.Try this